# Does the secure cookie work on http request with 443 port?

Tags: https

Does a Cookie with the secure flag work on Http request with 443 port?

For example) `http:443//www.example.com`

And how about ssl on Http request with 443 port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Does a Cookie with the secure flag work on Http request with 443 port?"*

-- No. A cookie with secure flag only works under HTTPS environment. HTTP request to port 443 (the default port of HTTPS) is still an HTTP, not HTTPS. Protocol is protocol, it won't be decided by which port is used.

According to [RFC6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265):

> The Secure attribute limits the scope of the cookie to "secure"
> channels (where "secure" is defined by the user agent).  When a
> cookie has the Secure attribute, the user agent will include the
> cookie in an HTTP request **only if** the request is transmitted over a
> secure channel (typically HTTP over Transport Layer Security (TLS)

HTTP request to port 443 is not transmitted over a secure channel.

I made a simple experiment, and the result is listed as below:

1. Make a web server, listen to port 443, with HTTP protocol. It works well.
2. On above server, return cookie without secure flag. The browser received the cookie and store it successfully.
3. On above server, return cookie with secure flag. The browser received the cookie, but ignore it automatically, as the current protocol is HTTP, not HTTPS.

*"How about ssl on Http request with 443 port?"*

-- There is no SSL on HTTP request with 443 port. 443 is a plain, normal number, there is nothing special for it. It's just being choosed as the default port of HTTPS, nothing more.